# Pulseaudio does not detect analog speakers, only HDMI output possible

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 15.10

Asus Z87-Pro (onboard Sound ALC1150), Ubuntu 15.10, Gnome3.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xefd34000 irq 34
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xefd30000 irq 33
```

Gnome sound settings and pulseaudio (e.g. `pavucontrol`) only offer to use HDMI output (sound card 0). pavucontrol > configuration shows two internal devices, first offering some HDMI output options, second card listing some analog output options (2.0, 5.1,... + many other options) but all those lines end with "(unplugged)".

Manually selecting the card works, and the following command is working as it should; I hear the voice from the connected speakers.

```
aplay -c1 whatever.wav
```

So I assume the speakers are connected as they should and pulseaudio's jack detection is broken somehow.

Strange detail: there is one single situation presenting perfect sound: it's the sound when logging off...

Is there any way to override jack detection? All threads found so far handle missing device drivers (i.e. card not recognized at all), renaming devices...

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my quite similar problems in this post: [Only have HDMI / Display Port for sound except Analog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952861/only-have-hdmi-display-port-for-sound-except-analog/952945#952945). You could try my way by reinstalling `analog` package:

```
sudo apt-get remove analog
sudo apt-get install analog
```

Reboot it and your computer may work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing jackd:

```
sudo aptitude install jackd
```

JACK Audio Connection Kit (default server package) is a low-latency sound server, allowing multiple applications to connect to one audio device, and to share audio between themselves.

[image: jack retask dialog]

See if that's what you want.

Normally jack detection/unplugged does not affect operation of the device. Remember it's not perfect even in Windows with official drivers.

#### Pavucontrol:

Manual selection between analog or hdmi is not related to jack detection. That is the correct method because both analog and hdmi are normally connected at the same time, but output is only sent to one depending on your need. If you never use either of those, then you can just select 'Off' for that, and the other will always be used.