# Only have HDMI / Display Port for sound except Analog

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I have a problem with sound in Ubuntu 16.04. Instead of having Speakers listed on `Choose a device for sound input` in Sound window, I have nothing and also that means I cannot hear any sounds from my laptop. I switch to Windows, which runs dual-boot with Ubuntu, and it doesn't detect my sound, too.

In Ubuntu, I also increase, decrease sound by short key, and I see instead of it shows Speaker, it shows **HDMI / Display Port**.

I try to type `sudo aplay -l` from terminal, I only got these HDMI devices **except Analog** like suggestions of https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1404/:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Tried hard to follow any suggestions from another solutions but no one of them could help me resolve this problem. Could anyone help me detect the problems I got and help me enabling my speakers like the default? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just only reinstall `analog` package:

```
sudo apt-get remove analog
sudo apt-get install analog
```

Reboot Ubuntu. Try `sudo aplay -l` again and Analog devices is shown in lists:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3246 Analog [ALC3246 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

That's all!

Comment: The package description of "Analog" says  "Analog is a fast log file processor that generates usage statistic reports
for web servers."  How can this be relevant?  Or have you got it from somewhere other than the canonical depot?